# is there any specific sensor nodes in ns3 simulator? what types of sensors does ns3 have?

Tags: ns-3

i want to do a simulation on IoT sensors in ns3. does ns3 has any specific sensors such as temp sensor or other sensors? or it just specifies as sensor nodes?

Answer (score 0):

There are no IoT-type sensor classes in ns-3 at the moment, but it appears there was desire for such functionality [in 2013](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/GSOC2013Projects#Simulating_the_Internet_of_Things_in_NS-3).

As an aside, ns-3 is a network simulator. It's not meant to simulate specific devices – rather, it simulates the network traffic of devices. If you can determine the traffic pattern of a device, than you can build an [Application](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_application.html) that generates this type of traffic, and install that Application on a Node. You may find inspiration for how to wrap your own Application by looking at the existing Applications. You might also be able to mimic the traffic pattern of IoT devices using an existing Application.